# Jquery OR operator not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The function below doesn't seem to work and I can't tell if my query is wrong or my php. `$num_rows` returns a value of `3` in a previous php script on the same page.

```
$('.markTD').click(function () {
    var qnum = $(this).attr('value');
    if (qnum != 1 || qnum != <?php echo $num_rows ?> ) {
        $('#submit').css("display", "none");
        $('#next').css("display", "block");
        $('#prev').css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add `complete` code or create `jsfiddle`

Comment: What's the value of `qnumb`? Keep in mind that you're comparing a string to a number.

Comment: @Tushar please dont edit the codes, he left some space between `<?php`. We cant help him if we edit the codes. in some aspects a small sp ace will create non-sense.

Comment: @KirsSudh: If you look at the revision history, he introduced it in an earlier edit. ...Tushar: There's no need to spam questions with off-topic tags.

Comment: @LyeFish qnum is a number.  is the reason the code isn't working bc im not comparing numbers to numbers?

Comment: @user176105: It's actually a string. All attributes are returned as string values. When comparing strings, you can get unexpected results, like `"10" < "3" // true`

Comment: so if it's a string, it needs to be wrapped in quotes `qnum != "<?php echo $num_rows ?>" )`

Comment: @Fred-ii-: He doesn't want a string. He wants numbers. If the `num_rows` is creating a number, then I think the `qnum` would also be converted. Ultimately we need to see the values.

Comment: @LyeFish that's why I wrote "if" ;-) you wrote in a comment *"It's actually a string. All attributes are returned as string values...."* - I wasn't feeding off that comment, but stating to the OP that if whatever is coming back and is a string, then that statement should be wrapped in quotes. OP needs to show us more code, check their console, and check for errors on both PHP and MySQL side of things ;-)

Comment: I think your logic is just messed up. You have two `!=` with an `||`. As long as `num_rows` isn't `1`, it'll always be `true`. But then your question doesn't say exactly what *"doesn't work"* means. How do we know what the result should be? Maybe you want to make sure `qnum` isn't equal to `1` AND (`&&`) it isn't equal to `num_rows`???

Comment: ...put it this way, if we get to the right side of the `||`, we know for sure that `qnum` is `1` and so the only way it will fail is if `num_rows` is also `1`.

Comment: @squint thanks.  i was trying to say, "if qnum is not 1 or 3  then execute this code"  like, if qnum is 2 then I would like the code to execute and I don't want the code to execute if qnum is 1 or if qnum is 3

Comment: @squint THANKS IT WORKED!  i swapped the `||` for `&&` and it worked perfectly.  please add this as an answer so i can accept it. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the input value from string to number, like below.

Oh, **and use `.val()` function** instead of `.attr('value')` :)

```
$('.markTD').click(function () {
    var qnum = parseInt($(this).val() || 0, 10);
    if (qnum != 1 || qnum != <?php echo $num_rows ?> ) {
        $('#submit').css("display", "none");
        $('#next').css("display", "block");
        $('#prev').css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

Comment: you have a typo "parsent" - that should most likely be "parent" as per documentation https://api.jquery.com/parent/ - Edit: seems it's `parseInt` and not `parent`. My mistake. But there was a typo though.

Comment: @user176105 ah, maybe... just maybe. Try both.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Of course, I forgot an `I` ;) Edited, thanks.

Comment: @TomekSułkowski thanks, but I tried this code and it still didn't work :[

Comment: @user176105 oh man, I'm sorry, didn't notice the obvious suspect :D try `.val()` function instead of .attr('value') (I've updated the answer)